# Feign Client Custom Configuration Does Not Take Effect

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I use feign in my project. I created a custom configuration but it is overridden by default configuration. Here are the steps:

**SpringBootApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
public class MyApplication {}
```

**FeignConfiguration.java**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FeignConfiguration{

private final MyConfigurationProperties myConfigProperties;

@Bean
public MetaDataRestClient metaDataRestClient(@Qualifier("metaDataHttpClient") okhttp3.OkHttpClient metaDataHttpClient) {
    return Feign.builder()
            .retryer(Retryer.NEVER_RETRY)
            .client(new OkHttpClient(metaDataHttpClient))
            .encoder(new JacksonEncoder(XML_MAPPER))
            .decoder(new JacksonDecoder(XML_MAPPER))
            .contract(new SpringMvcContract())
            .logger(new Slf4jLogger(MetaDataRestClient.class))
            .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
            .target(MetaDataRestClient.class, myConfigProperties.getMetadata().getEndpoint());
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "metaDataHttpClient")
public okhttp3.OkHttpClient metaDataHttpClientWithProxy() {
    return OkHttpUtil.createNewHttpClientBuilderWithProxy(myConfigProperties.getMetadata().getFeignClient().getConnectTimeout(),
            myConfigProperties.getMetadata().getFeignClient().getReadTimeout()).build();
}
```

**MetaDataRestClient.java**

```
@FeignClient(name = "metaDataRestClient", url = "https://myurl.net", configuration = FeignConfiguration.class)
public interface MetaDataRestClient {

    @Headers("Content-Type: text/xml")
    @GetMapping("/metadata")
    public EntityDescriptor getMetadaData();

}
```

I see that the `metaDataRestClient` bean is triggered on startup, but when I dig into feign library code, I see that this method is triggered twice: first time with my custom OkHttpClient, and second time with somehing called `org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.client.feign.LazyClient`. So my custom OkHttpClient is overridden by this lazy client.

Here is the related Feign library code that is being triggered twice:

**FeignBuilder.java**

```
 public Builder client(Client client) {
   this.client = client;
   return this;
}
```

I do not have any feign configurationn in my application.yaml file. What could be the reason for that?

Thanks.